# change router view in laravel by vuejs

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I am learning Vuejs (v3.2.36) in laravel framework (v10.22). I want to change the codes in the Vuejs file. The problem is that the project does not work. Vuejs files are as follows.

**/resources/js/app.js**

```
import './bootstrap';
import Router from '@/router'
import store from '@/store'
import { createApp } from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
const app = createApp({})
app.use(Router)
app.use(store)
app.component("my-component", Router)
app.mount('#app')
```

**/resources/js/router/index.js**

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from 'vue-router'
import store from '@/store'
const routes = [
    {
        name: "home",
        path: "/",
        component: () => import('@/components/Home.vue'),
        meta: {
            title: `..Home..`,
            middleware: "guest",
            requiresAuth: false,
        }
    },
    {
        name: "login",
        ...
    },
    ...
    {
        path: "/dashboard",
        component: () => import('@/layouts/Default.vue'),
        meta: {
            middleware: "auth",
            requiresAuth: true,
        },
    children: [
        {
        name: "dashboard",
        path: "/dashboard",
            component: () => import('@/components/Dashboard.vue'),
        ...
        }
    ]
     }
]
const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    document.title = to.meta.title
    if (to.meta.middleware == "guest") {
        if (store.state.auth.authenticated) {
            if (to.meta.pageLogin) {
                next({name: "dashboard"})
            }
        }
        next()
    } else {
        if (store.state.auth.authenticated) {
            next()
            return;
        }
        next({ name: "login" })
    }
})
export default router
```

**/resources/js/layouts/Default.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <nav>
           LoGo
        </nav>
        <main>
            <router-view></router-view>
        </main>
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import {mapActions} from 'vuex';
export default {
    name:"default-layout",
    components: {
    },
    data(){
        return {
        }
    },
    methods:{
        ...mapActions({
            signOut:"auth/logout"
        }),
        async logout(){
            await axios.post('/logout').then(({data})=>{
                this.signOut()
                this.$router.push({name:"login"})
            })
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

**/resources/js/components/Home.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
    This is Home page.
    </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapActions } from 'vuex'
export default {
    name:"home",
    data(){
        return {
        }
    },
    methods:{

    }
}
</script>
```

**/resources/js/components/Dashboard.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        This is Dashboard page.
    </div>
</template>
<script>
    export default {
        name:"dashboard",
        data(){
            return {
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            axios.get('api/user/1').then( (res) => {
                this.user = res.data
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

The **app.blade.php** file is as follows (laravel).
**/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
...
<body>
<div id="app">
    <my-component></my-component>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Error:

```
[Vue warn]: Component is missing template or render function. 
  at <MyComponent> 
  at <App> runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:38:16
```

The error says the name `MyComponent` is not defined.

Comment: Just use ```inertiajs``` to do laravel with vue. [even the official docs recommends it](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/frontend#inertia)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

app.js

```
...
import { createApp,h } from 'vue'
const app  = createApp({
    render: ()=>h(App)
});
...
```

app.blade.php

```
...
<body>
   <div id="app"></div>
</body>
...
```